# Is it possible to run gulp-notify in a watch task?

Tags: gulp, watch, notify

I'm putting together a gulpfile and I was wondering if you can combine `gulp-notify` (or some other solution) with a watch task so that a message pops up when the watch task has started running. I can't find anything from my searches on how I would go about doing this. Is it even possible?

Here's my watch task:

```
// Watch our files for changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  // -- I wanna run a notify message here saying 'Watching for changes...' -- //

  gulp.watch('assets/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('assets/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('assets/images/**/*', ['images']);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    notify("Watching for changes...").write('');

    gulp.watch('assets/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('assets/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('assets/images/**/*', ['images']);
});
```

Also, if you meant to have a notification each time a file changes, you could do something like this:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    //...

    gulp.watch([
        './src/**/*.html',
        './src/**/*.php',
    ]).on('change', function () {
        browserSync.reload();
        notify("File changed: browser synced").write('');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with gulp-notify and node-notifier.
After you gulp tasks pipe the notifier and in the callback use the node-notifier to show the popup.

```
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var nodeNotifier = require('node-notifier');

gulp().src(options.src)
.pipe(gulp.dest(options.dest))
.pipe(notify(function () {
    nodeNotifier.notify({
        'title': 'App',
        'message': 'Build'
    });
}));
```

Answer (score -2):

Can't you just use

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {

  console.log('Watching for changes...');

  gulp.watch('assets/styles/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('assets/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch('assets/images/**/*', ['images']);
});
```

Comment: That would just print it to the console, which is as useless as not having it at all since I don't wanna have to look there to see when it has started.